# CosmosDB: how to query for the existence of a value nested in a json array?

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-cosmosdb

My DB instance contains some documents with the following schema:

```
{
    id: <someGuid>
    myJsonArray: [
        {
            subId: SmallUniqueId1,
            val: <someValue>
        },
        {
            subId: SmallUniqueId2,
            val: <someOtherValue> 
        }
    ]
}
```

I have a Web API that generates new SubIds (you can think of them as randomly generated base64 strings that have a max length of 5 chars).

I'd like to query my DB to verify that the newly minted SubId doesn't already exist somewhere in all of my docs.

I figured the solution probably involves plugging in the new subId value into a WHERE clause (I'm hitting CosmosDB via the REST API).  Here's what I don't know:

- I don't know how to query over every element of each document's JsonArray (if it was just querying on a single string field, it would be easy)
- I'm also not sure about the efficiency of this query and whether this approach for validating new Ids against what's already in the DB is, in general, a bad pattern.  I have a one partition CosmosDB instance - the subId validation check should not occur very often.

Comment: Hi, any updates now ?

Comment: Give me a few more days to get back to you - had a few fires to put out.  I'm intrigued by the UDF suggestion at the bottom!  (Thank you!)

I have a scenario where I need to migrate these docs from one cosmosdb instance to another, and there's no guarantee that these subIds (which are valid in db1) are ALSO valid in db2.  

I need to think that through a bit before following up.

Comment: Sure! Waiting for your reply.

Answer (score 5):

> I don't know how to query over every element of each document's
>   JsonArray (if it was just querying on a single string field, it would
>   be easy)

I created two sample documents in my `azure cosmosdb` as you described.

```
[
  {
    "id": "id1",
    "myJsonArray": [
      {
        "subId": "sub1",
        "val": "value1"
      },
      {
        "subId": "sub2",
        "val": "value2"
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    "id": "id2",
    "myJsonArray": [
      {
        "subId": "sub3",
        "val": "value3"
      },
      {
        "subId": "sub4",
        "val": "value4"
      }
    ],
  }
]
```

You could use the `SQL` below to query `field` in array.

```
SELECT  a.subId as subId FROM c
join a in  c.myJsonArray
```

***Result:***

[image]

Add `where clause` .

```
SELECT  a.subId as subId FROM c
join a in  c.myJsonArray
where a.subId='sub1'
```

***Result:***

[image]

> I'm also not sure about the efficiency of this query and whether this
>   approach for validating new Ids against what's already in the DB is,
>   in general, a bad pattern. I have a one partition CosmosDB instance -
>   the subId validation check should not occur very often.

As you needs,I thought you could use `User Defined Function` in Azure Cosmos DB.

Invoke `UDF`  when you create document into your DB, check if the field value already exists, return the `boolean` result.

Please refer to this [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/programming#udf).

Hope it helps you. Any concern,please feel free to let me know.